# /dev/sdaX and /dev/disk/by-label/FOO are disappearing

Tags: linux

We operate about 35,000 machines running kernel version 3.7.0 with udev version 171. The kernel has aufs patches and some other patches related to V4L2.

On about 200 of the machines, some combination of `/dev/sdaX` and, sometimes, the by-label for it are missing. The vast majority (about 90%) of these are simply something wrong with the swap partition, the remaining 10% are more critical failures that would prevent boot or other important operations.

I've investigated a few and found that some of the following will sometimes resolve the problem.

1. Sometimes `partprobe` will cause a missing by-label to reappear. That is, for example, `/dev/sda6` exists but `/dev/disk/by-label/OVERLAYB` does not. Running `partprobe` restores `OVERLAYB`.
2. Sometimes, the same symptoms are observed, but `partprobe` does nothing.
3. Sometimes, a partition appears corrupted in a way that the label is lost. For example, `/dev/sda3` exists, but `/dev/disk/by-label/SWAP` is missing and `swapon /dev/sda3` fails with `read swap header failed: Invalid argument`. `mkswap` corrects this.
4. Sometimes, a partition and its by-label are missing. A combination of `mknod` and `mkfs` restore the expected behavior.
5. In another case, `/dev/sdaX` and its by-label were missing. After `mknod`, `mkfs` (with the appropriate `-L`), and a paranoid `partprobe`, the by-label was still missing.

Of note is that I have never seen `/proc/partitions` be incorrect, even when a `/dev/sdaX` is missing.

Also of note, in a few cases, the current root filesystem had a missing `/dev/sdaX` mode. This would prevent boot! That indicates to me that the node exists on boot but later disappeared. Nothing seemed odd in `dmesg`.

I know this is a lot of different stuff going on, but I believe that these are all symptoms of some deeper failure that we have not found. I believe that in correcting a problem, I'm only undoing a symptom and that the problem will happen again.

I'm really at a loss of what else to look at. Has anyone seen anything like this before? What could the underlying problem be? How do I even learn more about the situation, to help me narrow down the problem space?

Answer (score 1):

Faced the similar issue with Crucial M500 SSD drives.
The drives suddenly disappeared but to see them again power off/on was required.
Upgrading the drive firmware from MU02 to MU05(the latest) fixes the issue.
The mystery can also be related to BIOS and drive controller firmware version.